# Spring 4 hibernate 4 JPA LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, lazy-initialization

I made a database connection with spring 4 used with hibernate 4 and JPA. When I try to get a lazy initializated field I got an LazyInitializationException.

My applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="xy" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="xy.repositories" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />

</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keysystem" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long employeeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employee")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<Legitimacy> legitimacies;
    ...
```

I found only MVC filter solution, but I don't use MVC. I tried Hibernate.initialize(...) and @Transational, @Fetch annotations but these didn't solved my problem.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: xy.Employee.legitimacies, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
    ... 64 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318404/jpa-how-to-return-null-instead-of-lazyinitializationexception/33325493#33325493 
Accepted answer explains why it happens and how to solve it. There's no trick to it, if you try to access the contents of `legitimacies` Set outside of a transaction while it still has not been fully initialized, you will get this exception.

Comment: The @Transactional annotation didn't work for me, and I don't want to use Eager initialization because of the performace.

Comment: Then I think you should provide two more parts of code so we can identify the exact problem and how to solve it. Please add the code you use to fetch  the Employee object, and the code where you try to access the legitimacies Set content. What you could do is to initialize the Set while the hibernate session is still open.

Comment: Also, saying "this didn't solve my problem" is not helpful at all. Instead, you should explain why it didn't solve your problem. For example, why Hibernate.initialize didn't work for you? This method has only one intent, to initialize the collection, if it's called within a transaction it should initialize your Set and you should not have any problems accessing its contents later on.

Answer (score 1):

Guillaume is right, you are using a proxy managed by Hibernate in some location in your code which is outside a transactional context.

Because of that, when you call `getLegitimacies()` that has not been initialized yet, Hibernate try to populate its proxy by graping a session and make a database call.

If you are in a controller for example and no session is available, an exception is thrown. You have to fetch your legitimacies set at some point in your dao (by using **FETCH** keyword in your HQL query for example) :

```
FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.legitimacies WHERE <your_predicate>;
```

You should also not manipulate your entities if not in service/dao layer but use a DTO instead to avoid those problems.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy exceptions occurs when you try to access a referenced object outside of the original session.

Basically, you are doing this :

```
* Open a session
* Fetch an object, let's say X
* Close the session
* Try to access X.getY()
```

A solution is to fetch X and Y at the same time, while the session is open.